# Excel percentage of NaN values in a column

Tags: excel

A very basic question in excel.
I have a column with valid and with invalid(NaN) values.
I want to calculate the percentage of NaN values in the column, and not through a filter, any quick way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNT(B1:B10) / ROWS(B1:B10)
```

Comment: How so @fammi? Please be specific

Comment: it computes percentage of valid values, just use `=1-(...)` :)